# how do I fix my flutter app not building with cloud firestore?

Tags: java, flutter, firebase, dart

So I am new to flutter and firebase and I wanted to add firestore capabilities to my app, but when I tried to use firestore I got an error

> The plugin cloud_firestore requires a higher Android SDK version.                             │
> │ Fix this issue by adding the following to the file                                            │
> │ C:\Users\Jaff\StudioProjects\priv_chat\android\app\build.gradle:

After fixing the SDK version, then I got another error,

> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-3.4.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
> import com.google.firebase.firestore.TransactionOptions;
> symbol:   class TransactionOptions
> location: package com.google.firebase.firestore
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-3.4.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java:66: error: package TransactionOptions does not exist
> new TransactionOptions.Builder().setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts).build(),

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

This is where I got completely confused, I have no idea how to solve this, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue and noticed, that my `firebase_core` dependency in pubspec.yaml was not updated.

Now I use `firebase_core: ^1.20.0` and it works

Do not forget to run `flutter clean`.

Hope that helps :)